# Separate built jar and dependency jars

Tags: kotlin, gradle

The application plugin copies the start scripts into 'bin', and copies the built jar and all dependencies into 'lib' ([see here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaApplication.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaApplication:applicationDistribution)). How can I separate the dependency jars and the built jar. I would like to have the build jar in the root folder and change the classpath correspondingly. Tried the change "applicationDistribution" property with include/exclude but this does not work.

I'm able to do:

```
tasks.installDist {
    from("$buildDir/libs") {
        include("myLib*.jar")
    }
    doLast {
        delete(fileTree("$buildDir/install/${project.name}/lib") {
            include("myLib*.jar")
        })
    }
}
```

But this only works for `installDist` and does no reflect to `distZip`. How can I move the a jar from the 'lib' folder so that it will work for `installDist`, `distZip` and changes the `classspath`?
Classpath could probably be changed in `tasks.startScripts`, but therefor the jar should move correctly.
I'm using the Gradle Kotlin DSL.

Desired output would be something like this, where *myBuilt.jar* is moved from lib to root:

```
myProgram/
├── lib/
│   ├── lib1.jar
│   ├── lib2.jar
│   ├── ...
├── myProgram.bat
└── myBuilt.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I used eachFile (which I was not aware of before) an changed the destination directory:

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            eachFile {
                if (sourceName.matches( Regex("myLib.*\\.jar"))) {
                    relativePath = RelativePath(true,
                        *relativePath.parent.replaceLastName(sourceName).segments)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The classpath for the start scripts has to be changed manually because CreateStartScript hard-coded the classpaths and appends "lib/" ([see here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/2d23baf5e58b39062413de86382b4ede785f5445/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/jvm/application/tasks/CreateStartScripts.java#L397)).

```
var jarFileName = ""; // is filled in tasks.jar with archiveFileName
tasks.startScripts {
    doLast {
        val windowsScriptContent = windowsScript.readText().replace("%APP_HOME%\\lib\\$jarFileName",
            "%APP_HOME%\\$jarFileName")
        windowsScript.writeText(windowsScriptContent)
    }
}
```

Alternative would be to make a runnable jar: insert classpath into manifest and modify starting script template.